# Uniform convergence of series of function defined by recurrence formula

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I have the exercise.

> Let $ \{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} $ be a series of functions on $I = [0,1]$ defined with
> $f_1(x) =x, f_{n+1}=\sqrt{f_{n}(x)+2}$
>
> (1) Show $ \{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} $ is bounded for each $x \in I$ and $f_n(x) \leq f_{n+1}(x)$
>
> (2) $ \{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} $ is uniformly convergent on $I$
>
> (3) Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_I f_{n}(x) dx$

I can solve only (1).

(1) We show $f_n(x) \leq 2$. $n=1$ is obvious. Suppose it is true for $n=k$. Then $f_{k+1}=\sqrt{f_{k}(x)+2} \leq \sqrt{4} =2$.
Next, $f_{1}(x) \leq f_{2}(x)$ for each $x$ is obvious, since $1 \leq f_{2}(x)$ for all $x \in I$. For general $n$, this is shown with induction.

(2)(my approach) $f_n$ is pointwise convergent, so suppose convergent to $f$. Let $g_n = 2- f_n$. If I can show $f$ is continuous, then by using Dini's thorem to $g$ and get result.

(3)(my approach) From (2), $\int_I \lim_{n \to \infty} f_{n}(x) dx$ is essential.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As it converges point wise, then may be will be helpful, that $f$ can be calculated from $f^2=f+2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\lim f_n(x)$. Then $f(x)=\sqrt {f(x)+2}$ so $y^{2}-y-2=0$ where $y=f(x)$. Solving this quadratic equation we get $y=f(x)=2$ or $f(x) =-1$. But $f_n \geq 0$ for all $n$  so $f(x) \geq 0$. Hence $f(x)=2$ for all $x$. Also $\int f_n(x)dx=\int 2 dx=2$ by Monotone Convergnce Theorem  or DCT or by 2).  Your argument for 2) is fine.